# Create a new column with a condition of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two DF's

```
df1
  Zone                            Tarif
  <dbl>                           <dbl>
1     1                           0.125
2     2                           0.217
3     3                           0.307
4     4                           0.387
5     5                           0.449
6     6                           0.580
7     7                           0.684
8     8                           0.894
```

and

```
df2
   state total shipments koerier zone_shipments koerierkosten gewichtkoerier gewichtzone zone
AZ    AZ             453      91            362           637           1092    702226.2    6
CA    CA            2176     436           1740          3052           5232   2964741.2    5
ID    ID             261      53            208           371            636    431186.9    2
MT    MT             526     106            420           742           1272    485048.1    2
NV    NV             265      53            212           371            636    484546.3    5
OR    OR             410      82            328           574            984    591250.8    3
WA    WA             521     105            416           735           1260    798673.8    1
```

I want to create a new colum in df2 (`df2$tarif`) with the paired zone and tarif value from df1.
Example: if df2$zone = 6 then df2$tarif = 0.580 (information from df1)

Expected Output

```
df2
   state total shipments koerier zone_shipments koerierkosten gewichtkoerier gewichtzone zone  tarif
AZ    AZ             453      91            362           637           1092    702226.2    6   0.580
CA    CA            2176     436           1740          3052           5232   2964741.2    5   0.449
ID    ID             261      53            208           371            636    431186.9    2   0.217
MT    MT             526     106            420           742           1272    485048.1    2   0.217
NV    NV             265      53            212           371            636    484546.3    5   0.449
OR    OR             410      82            328           574            984    591250.8    3   0.307
WA    WA             521     105            416           735           1260    798673.8    1   0.125
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `join`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   left_join(df1, by = c("zone" = "Zone"))
```

---

Or with `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(df2, df1, by.x = 'zone', by.y = 'Zone', all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `merge` for this:

```
df2 <- merge(df2, df1, by.x = "Zone")
```